# Mongodb mongoose models export them all from an index.js file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My project structure is like this

```
src
 /models
 -Session.js
 -Screen.js
 -Event.js
 -index.js
 /controllers
```

Simply what I want is to export all these models using my index.js file. So then I can easily use that in my controller files like this

**sessionController.js**

```
const db = require('../models')
db.Session.find()
```

To achieve this I tried this so far

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const db ={}
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => file !== 'index.js')
  .forEach(file =>{

  })

module.exports = db;
```

But I can't think how to export these in a such a way.
How do I achieve this using `node.js`?

Comment: You have to create a class and function inside it after that you have to export like this `module.exports = Welcome` and import it in any file then you can use it like `Welcome.index()` or `Welcome.myFunction`

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js import all the other model files.

```
const session = require('./Session');
const event = require('./Event');
const screen = require('./Screen');
```

Then you can export them all like:

```
module.exports = {session, event, screen};
```

Now `const db = require('../models')` will give you an object with all your models in one place.